# Management form error while using modelformsets ('ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with')

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a models.py class as below

```
class Educational_Qualification(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   exam = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   pass_month = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

I have a views.py as below

```
def create_qualification(request):
 QFormSet = modelformset_factory(Educational_Qualification, extra=3, exclude=("user",))
 if request.method == "POST":
  formset = QFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)

  if formset.is_valid():
   formset.save()
   for form in formset.forms:
    if form.is_valid():
     quali= form.save(commit=False)
     quali.user = request.user
     quali.save()

    return HttpResponse("Saved")
  else:
   return HttpResponse("Snafu")
 else:
  formset = QFormSet()
 return render_to_response("register/edu.html", {"formset":formset}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When I submit the form, it throws up the validation Error. stating that ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with'

I have formset.management_form in my template.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 25):

The error is not in your views or the models, but in the templates.

The right way to render the formset, is:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <table>
        {{ formset }}
    </table>
</form>
```

or

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <table>
        {% for form in formset.forms %}
            {{ form }}
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</form>
```

I guess, you are looping over the forms in the templates without including the management form?

Answer (score 0):

It also happens if there are multiple views involved and one of them is not aware of the formset prefix.

Get view:

```
def someview(request):
...
    formset = Formset(prefix="foo")
...
```

Post view (Potentially an Ajax form submit handler):

```
def ajaxview(request):
...
    formset = Formset(request.POST, prefix="foo")  # here
...
```